Confusion about dependency of events
Assume that we have an urn consisting of 10 blue and 5 red balls. Now we want to perform an experiment with it as follows:
First, we draw a ball from the urn and note its color. Then, if it's red, we toss a dice and, if it's blue, we will throw a coin that has two possibilities (heads and tails).
Now we want to calculate the probability of drawing a blue ball from the urn in this experiment. How do you calculate such a quested probability?
I think you would just say
$P(B) = \frac{\binom{10}{1}}{\binom{15}{1}}$ (where $B$ is the event that we get a blue)
But where does it come from? Did we assume the event $B$ is independent from other events? Why didn't we care about the rest of the experiment which is tossing a dice or throwing a coin? What's the reason that we just don't care about those?

It seems they threw in the stuff about the die and the coin just to be confusing.  There are $15$ balls, $10$ of which are blue so the probability of choosing a blue one is $\frac {10}{15}$, what happens after that is irrelevant.  Or perhaps there were other questions about the scenario?

Actually I have added it on by myself . But the purpose of doing this is to know why we don't care about those ? are these two sub-experiments totally independent from each other that we would calculate the probability of getting a blue in the first sub-expriment or like this something else is causing it ?

Of course they are dependent, but so what?  Knowing that I will take some action or another based on the outcome of a chance event has no bearing on the probability of that outcome.  If I draw to an inside Royal Flush I will win a lot of money, but that doesn't make it likely to happen.

If you want a question that links your actions, you could try something like "given the game you describe, what is the probability that it ends with you tossing a $4$?"

you are correct, But my question is aiming for something else. Let me put it this way; can you please provide a mathematical argument on how do you calculate that probability ?
I think one way of doing this is to obtain the number of all possible outcomes that satisfy the constraint that the event B defines (which is being blue), And divide it by the number of all possible outcomes of the experiment right ?
but with that you would get a different result, don't take my work try it.

The possible outcomes are not equally probable.  The probability that it ends with you tossing a $4$ is $\frac 5{15}\times \frac 16$ while the probability that ends with you tossing Tails is $\frac {10}{15}\times \frac 12$, which is much greater.

Aha nice, you are absolutely correct sir @lulu.
But anyways it doesn't answer my first question which is asking for the exact argument that leads to obtaining such a probability for getting a blue ball. Can you please guide me through this please ?
